# Python - Running several OS command in parallel, using timeouts, and checking return codes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7 on linux/solaris, I need to spawn several OS commands in parallel; if a thread/command takes longer than a provided timeout, it kills the command. I've been trying to do this with threads but having trouble getting the return codes.

The command I am running is a simple dd command to an NFS-mounted filesystem. If this dd command times out, I need to grab the name of the mount point that failed and store this for later. I don't necessarily need the return code form the dd command but would like to collect the output. (my next project is a latency tool that will need the output from dd)

Here is my pseudo code:

```
<spawn several threads with each one running an OS command>

<after my timeout window, loop thru any remaining active threads and terminate them, or terminate the os command that thread is running>

<gather a list of threads (actually the mountpoint that I provided the thread), that timed out and save for later>
```

Am I going about this right or is there a more appropriate approach.

Much thx for any help.

Comment: One way can be using subprocess module with each command prefixed with timeout command  ($timeout 5s <your_command>) and join processes

Comment: You can't terminate threads per say, but if you use the subprocess module, you can terminate the subprocesses which would wake the babysitting thread and unwind everything. So, generally, your approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Something like this:

```
task_inputs = [
        'input1',
        'input2',
        ]

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, task_input):
        self.task_input = task_input
    def __call__(self):
        """Do your thing..."""

task_threads = []
for task_input in task_inputs:
    task = Task(task_input)
    thr = Thread(target=task)
    thr.start()
    task_threads.append((thr, task))

# wait for timeout

naughty_tasks = []
for thr, task in task_threads:
    if thr.is_alive():
        # still running!
        """Do your termination thing..."""
        naughty_tasks.append(task)


# now you have a list of Task object with their original input ( naughty_tasks[i].task_input )
```